# How to divide a face in two?

Tags: faces

i need to divide a face in two.

This is what I have now

[image]

And this is what I want to do

[image]

What is the correct way to do it?

I use Blender 2.8

Many Thanks

Comment: Put the Object into Edit Mode, and then Edge Select mode.  Select the two edges that border the face you want to "Divide";  RMB (right mouse button) and select "Subdivide", which will create the new vertices/edges at the halfway point.   Then change to Vertex Select mode, select the two new vertices, and move them to the point where you want that new edge to actually be positioned.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoU0OwO9R9E

Comment: If it's just a face on its own, i.e: on a a plane object, you can use Loop cut and Slide in Edit mode.. CTRL-R with the mouse near one of the edges then left-click once and slide the mouse up and down until you have the new edge where you want it and Left-click again to set its position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Knife tool

<kbd>K</kbd> for *Knife*, <kbd>C</kbd> for angle constraint, click on one side, click on the other, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm (I press <kbd>Numpad Enter</kbd> with my right thumb to not have to move either hand):

[image]

If your object is not aligned to cardinal/ordinal directions and yet you want the new edge to be aligned, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to snap to centers of edges for the same effect as described by james_t. Or you can just select the newly created edge, <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd> to *Edge Slide*, slide it all the way to one side, click to confirm, then again <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd> and slide it where you want.

### Subdivision

Stealing from james_t's comment, <kbd>2</kbd> for edge selection mode, select two edges, right-click, <kbd>S</kbd> to *Subdivide*, then you can *Edge Slide* as described above (or just vertex slide, whatever you need).

[image]

### Loop Cut and Slide

Stealing from John Eason again today, you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and move your mouse around until you get a proper *Loop Cut*, then click and slide where you want the new edge to be:

[image]

### Vertex Connect Path

You can do an equivalent of a knife cut between two existing vertices, if you select them and press <kbd>J</kbd>:

[image]

This also works in a chain like this:

[image]

Comment: Knife tool works. Many Thanks